# get FeUser usergroups title

Tags: php, typo3, backend

I want to get the title of a usergroup of a FeUser.

Problem is, that im only getting the UID of the usergroup and not the title.

```
$usergroup = $this->getFeUser()->user['usergroup'];
```

Can someone explain, why im only getting the UID and how to get the title of this UID?

Comment: $this->getFeUser()->getName() Does that work?

Comment: well i dont want to get the Username. 
im getting the username 
by $username = $this->getFeUser()->user['username'];
i want to get the title of his usergroup

Answer (score 2):

If I don't mistake this should give an `ObjectStorage` with the usergroup(s) as property:

```
$usergroup = $this->getFeUser()->getUsergroup();
```

To see which functions exist in the model-class you can open this class:

> TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser

`ObjectStorage` has usually this namespace: `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage` and is an iterable Object which can be used comparable with an array.

If for some reason an `ObjectStorage` is not desired but an array instead you can use the `toArray()` function on the result:

```
$usergroup = $this->getFeUser()->getUsergroup()->toArray();
```